# how does IPython's ? (question mark) operator actually work?

Tags: python, console, ipython, metaclass

So i was thinking that in order to implement such a feature in a console application , where appending a question mark at the end of a function name will pour out it's doc string , i would have probably used a feature like metaclasses , where upon definition/import , i'd duplicate all the module member names and produce new ones just for typing out doc strings.

Then i noticed that you don't need actual parenthesis to call the helper functions and python doesn't actually allow you to put a question mark at the end of the function name anyway.... So is this done in python or am i just wasting my time trying to figure this out?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not done the way you're imagining. ipython reads your command prompt input as a line of text, so it has a chance to check if it ends with a question mark before it passes it on to `eval` (or whatever). If it does, it runs `help(name)` instead of what you typed.

AST looks a little heavy-duty, but you can get a feel for how this works by checking out the module `code`. It gives you a lightweight interpreter that you can extend with syntax of this sort if you want.

Comment: Pretty much - in fact it translates it into `get_ipython().magic(u'pinfo name')`. You can see translated commands using `%hist -t`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `IPython.core.inputsplitter` module for the code that parses the raw input line for things like ?, !, /, %, etc.

Comment: Now `IPython.core.inputsplitter` is deprecated in favor of `IPython.core.inputtransformer2` https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/7.28.0/api/generated/IPython.core.inputtransformer2.html  or try `import IPython.core` and `IPython.core.inputtransformer2??`

Answer (score 0):

ipython uses [AST](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html),  you can customize the syntax parsing and create a new ipython fork.

may help

Comment: It does use AST, but not for this - the code has to be valid Python syntax before you can make an AST, and `name?` isn't.